# Cannot use my ASMX web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have built this web service that returns all of the links from one table in SQL. I saw a lot of tutorials where they just added a new web reference to the project and they choose Web Services from the project ,they choose the web service that they want and they click add reference,and then they just created a new web site and they used this code to call it:

```
WebServiceLinks.Service proxy = new WebServiceLinks.Service();
WebServiceLinks.Vezvi Links = proxy.GetLinks();
```

and then they just passed this to a label. When i try to write WebServiceLinks , I cant find the Service class. This is the code that I have wrtitten.
(I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010).

**Code**:

```
public static string GetLinks()
{

    string query = string.Format("SELECT Link FROM Linkovi");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = query;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Append(reader["Link"].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

and this is how i call the method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetLinks()
{
    return ConnectionClass.GetLinks();
}
```

Also, if I'm able to pass this to a label, is it possible to add a break between the links?

This link helped me how to solve my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOqEKpYbTzw

Comment: how does your service contract look like?

Comment: where can i see that? I'm sorry, it is my first time creating a web service..

Comment: I sume this is a WCF service? you service class (usually a svc.cs file) should implement a interface this is the service contract.

Comment: I'm not sure what is WCF... I created a ASP .NET project, and then on the project I just added new item and then I just selected Web Service it is named WebServiceLinks.asmx and the class WebServiceLinks.asmx.cs

Comment: Oh asmx are the old style services in .Net you should realy use WCF

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score -2):

If it's a asmx file, then in Visual Studio go to the Web References folder, expand that and you should see the service there.  Right click on the service and click View in Object Browser.  That should open up the Object Browser and show you the namespace of the class you need to use.  It might be something like:
MyWebsite.MyService
where MyWebsite is probably the name of your project and MyService the name of your service.  Then in code just write

```
MyWebsite.MyService service = new MyWebSite.MyService();
```

that should get it for you.

Comment: -1: it's possible (and preferable) to use "Add Service Reference" to reference an ASMX service.